# Android WebView Cannot Load html

Tags: android, html

I want to load html file when application runs. I tried on my cell phone but it's not working.
I'm trying to load the html file in the WebView. Below html file gets loaded but at run time these (01,02,03...) html files not loaded.

This is my html code:

```
<html>
    <FRAMESET rows="18%,38%,38%,6%" border="0">
    <FRAMESET cols="100%,%,%,%"border="0">
        <frame src="01.htm" scrolling="no" />
        <frame src="02.htm" scrolling="no" />
        <frame src="03.htm" scrolling="no" />
        <frame src="04.htm" scrolling="no" />
    </frameset>
    <FRAMESET cols="25%,25%,25%,25%"border="0">
        <frame src="05.htm" scrolling="no" />
        <frame src="06.htm" scrolling="no" />
        <frame src="07.htm" scrolling="no" />
        <frame src="08.htm" scrolling="no" />
    </frameset>
    <FRAMESET cols="25%,25%,25%,25%"border="0">
        <frame src="09.htm" scrolling="no" />
        <frame src="10.htm" scrolling="no" />
        <frame src="11.htm" scrolling="no" />
        <frame src="12.htm" scrolling="no" />
    </frameset>
    <FRAMESET cols="100%,0%,0%,0%" border="0">
        <frame src="13.htm" scrolling="no" />
        <frame src="14.htm" scrolling="no" />
        <frame src="15.htm" scrolling="no" />
        <frame src="16.htm" scrolling="no" />
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: can you upload your xml and java file?

Comment: firslty. have you tried to load this html inside a browser?
also, please tell us in which folder have you put these html files? If you provide a directory structure, That would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you put one `FRAMESET` tag that missed its closing tag.

Also take care about the fact that `FRAMESET` tags [are not allowed in HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp).